# Android SQLite Error With Inserting Data

Tags: java, android

I was trying to input some data into a SQLite Database and I'm getting an error for every time that I try to add data.

*Error Message*
**HERE IS THE LOG:** [Error Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbwucxg8j7jqbei/ErrorLog.pdf?dl=0)

**Output**

```
02-11 18:36:36.050    1853-1872/com.teamnewb.sahil.bliss D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7f851d267800 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f851d25da40
02-11 18:36:37.680    1853-1853/com.teamnewb.sahil.bliss E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near ".": syntax error
    --------- beginning of crash
02-11 18:36:37.700    1853-1853/com.teamnewb.sahil.bliss E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.teamnewb.sahil.bliss, PID: 1853
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.teamnewb.sahil.bliss/com.teamnewb.sahil.bliss.ActionSummary}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE tasks (com.teamnewb.sahil.TaskContract.TASKDESC TEXT)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE tasks (com.teamnewb.sahil.TaskContract.TASKDESC TEXT)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
            at db.TaskDBHelper.onCreate(TaskDBHelper.java:28)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
            at db.TaskCRUD.insert(TaskCRUD.java:22)
            at com.teamnewb.sahil.bliss.ActionSummary.onCreate(ActionSummary.java:63)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-11 18:36:39.400    1897-1897/com.teamnewb.sahil.bliss D/addEventYet﹕ false
02-11 18:36:39.400    1897-1897/com.teamnewb.sahil.bliss D/Db is empty?﹕ Yes
```

**TaskContract.java**

```
  package db; 

    import android.provider.BaseColumns;

    import java.util.Calendar;

public class TaskContract {
     public static final String DB_NAME = "com.teamnewb.sahil.db.tasks";
     public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
     public static final String TABLE = "tasks";



 public static class Columns {
    public static final String TASKDESC = "taskdesc"; //TODO: get task description input here and other inputs as well
    public static final String DATEMONTH = "month";
    public static final String DATEDAY = "day";
    public static final String DATEYEAR = "year";
    public static final String TASKTYPE = "tasktype";
    public static final String IMP = "imp";

    //Variables used to transfer/store data
    public String description;
    public String type; //note if completed task store as COMPLETEDTASK
    public int year;
    public int month;
    public int day;
    public int im; //0 = not important, else 1

    public Columns(String d, String t, int i) {
        description = d;
        type = t;
        im = i;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = Calendar.MONTH;
    }

   }

  }
```

**TaskDBHelper.java**

```
package db;


 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
 import android.util.Log;

   public class TaskDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public TaskDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, TaskContract.DB_NAME, null, TaskContract.DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
    String sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + TaskContract.TABLE + "(" + TaskContract.Columns.TASKDESC + "TEXT, "
            + TaskContract.Columns.TASKTYPE + "TEXT, " + TaskContract.Columns.DATEYEAR + "INTEGER, " +
            TaskContract.Columns.DATEMONTH + "INTEGER, " + TaskContract.Columns.DATEDAY + "INTEGER, "
            + TaskContract.Columns.IMP + "INTEGER )";


    Log.d("TaskDBHelper", "Query to form table: " + sqlQuery);
    sqlDB.execSQL(sqlQuery);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB, int i, int i2) {
    sqlDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TaskContract.TABLE);
    onCreate(sqlDB);
  }
}
```

**TaskCRUD.java**

```
package db;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.util.Log;
public class TaskCRUD {
private TaskDBHelper dbHelper;

public TaskCRUD (Context context)
{
    dbHelper = new TaskDBHelper(context);
}

public boolean insert(TaskContract.Columns c)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TaskContract.Columns.DATEDAY, c.day);
    Log.d(TaskContract.Columns.DATEDAY, c.day + "");
    values.put(TaskContract.Columns.DATEMONTH, c.month);
    Log.d(TaskContract.Columns.DATEMONTH, c.month + "");
    values.put(TaskContract.Columns.DATEYEAR, c.year);
    Log.d(TaskContract.Columns.DATEYEAR, c.year + "");
    values.put(TaskContract.Columns.TASKDESC, c.description);
    Log.d(TaskContract.Columns.TASKDESC, c.description);
    values.put(TaskContract.Columns.TASKTYPE, c.type);
    Log.d(TaskContract.Columns.TASKTYPE, c.type);
    values.put(TaskContract.Columns.IMP, c.im);
    Log.d(TaskContract.Columns.IMP, c.im + "");
    db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TABLE,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    return true;
}

public boolean delete(String description)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    // It's a good practice to use parameter ?, instead of concatenate string
    db.delete(TaskContract.TABLE, description + "= ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(description) });
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
    return true;
}
public ArrayList<Tasks> getData(int m, int y) {
    ArrayList<Tasks> t = new ArrayList<Tasks>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String q = "SELECT * FROM " + TaskContract.TABLE + " WHERE " +
                TaskContract.Columns.DATEMONTH + " = " + m + " AND " + TaskContract.Columns.DATEYEAR + " = " + y + " ORDER BY "
                + TaskContract.Columns.DATEDAY + " DESC;";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(q, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
    if (c != null)
    {
        do {
            String desc = c.getString(0);
            String type = c.getString(1);
            int year = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(3));
            int month = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(4));
            int day = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(5));
            int imp = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(6));
            Tasks task = new Tasks(day, month, year, imp, desc, type);
            t.add(task);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        return t;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: try after changing version code `DB_VERSION = 1;` to `DB_VERSION = 2;`

Comment: Didn't work. Any other ideas guys?

Comment: i guess u hav missed a semicolon at the end.Folllow this:    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sale (isfav TEXT, ishidden TEXT, sale_id TEXT);";

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your `DB_NAME` to something like `tasks.db`. Your error may have something to do with the `DB_NAME`.

Also, modify your table create statement to include spaces after the column name is declared and just before you declare the column datatype.

```
String sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + TaskContract.TABLE + " ( " + TaskContract.Columns.TASKDESC + " TEXT, "
            + TaskContract.Columns.TASKTYPE + " TEXT, " + TaskContract.Columns.DATEYEAR + " INTEGER, " +
            TaskContract.Columns.DATEMONTH + " INTEGER, " + TaskContract.Columns.DATEDAY + " INTEGER, "
            + TaskContract.Columns.IMP + " INTEGER)";
```

Let me know if this helps.